# Method POST for One To One relation

Tags: java, rest, jpa, post, one-to-one

I'm trying to make a POST request to save `User` with `UserProfile` but I'm getting an error.

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "user")
public class User {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    private String login;

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade =  CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "user")
    private UserProfile userProfile;
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "user_profile")
public class UserProfile {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    private String name;

    @JsonIgnore
    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
    private User user;
}
```

**Is there a difference between this two POST methods?**

```java
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/user")
public class UserController {
    @PostMapping
    public User save(@RequestBody User user) {
        return userRepository.save(user);
    }

    @PostMapping("/anotherSave")
    public User anotherSave() {
        User user = new User();
        user.setLogin("Login");

        UserProfile userProfile = new UserProfile();
        userProfile.setName("Name");

        user.setUserProfile(userProfile);
        userProfile.setUser(user);

        return userRepository.save(user);
    }
}
```

The second works perfectly without mistakes. First one throws exception `Column 'user_id' cannot be null`. Http request below is how I use first POST method:

```
POST http://localhost:8080/api/user
Content-Type: application/json

{
  "login": "a",
  "userProfile": {
    "name": "A"
  }
}
```

**My request is incorrect or incorrectly built a relation?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have UserProfile.user ignored in your JSON request body, so I guess you would be fine with adding something like

```
user.getUserProfile().setUser(user);
```

in your first method before saving to the repository.

Comment: Actually this works. But I have an assumption that the save method does this on its own?

Comment: It doesn‘t - it just takes and saves the entities “as is“ and fails here because both your DB tables require foreign keys to each other and you did only provide one (User to UserProfile, since you put a `@JsonIgnore` on the other one). When _reading_ from the DB, JPA will resolve both properties automatically. Depending on your particular use-case it’s probably a better choice to just let one table have a foreign key to the other.